# Removing keypair from hash (Ruby) not actually making a difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, element

So I have a hash of names initialized and I am trying to get user input to remove a keypair from the hash. Here is my code:

```
group = {:sally => "Sally Samsonite", :johnny => "Johnny Jameson", :beth => "Beth Benitsky", :corinne => "Corinne Camelia"}

    print "Please enter a name to remove #{group.keys} >"
    group.except!(gets)
    group.each do |key, value|
        puts "#{value}"
    end
```

After running the program and inputting ":sally" the hash is returned as it's original:

```
Please enter a name to remove [:sally, :johnny, :beth, :corinne] >:sally
Sally Samsonite
Johnny Jameson
Beth Benitsky
Corinne Camelia
```

How do I delete the element permanently?

Answer (score 2):

`gets` returns a string with a newline at the end.

Your keys are symbol. There's no key named `":sally\n"` or `"sally\n"`, so removing it doesn't change anything in your hash.

You need to :

- remove the newline with `chomp`
- remove the prefix `:` if present
- convert to a symbol

---

```
group = {:sally => "Sally Samsonite", :johnny => "Johnny Jameson", :beth => "Beth Benitsky", :corinne => "Corinne Camelia"}

print "Please enter a name to remove #{group.keys} >"
group.delete(gets.chomp.sub(/^:/,'').to_sym)
group.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{value}"
end
```

Comment: Using 'gets.chomp.to_sym' still does not remove the keyvalue I input via terminal.

edit: Fixed it by using "gets.parameterize.to_sym"

Comment: @SamLim: Updated. This code now works with "sally" and ":sally" as input.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš 1) why would I? :) 2) Answering your question - nope, i did not.

Comment: I don't know I am just sensitive to this as I got a bad start because someone downvoted my questions :)